# Is this a a crazy enough reaction for someone who isn’t the most sane person, yet normal enough to be considered a human reaction?

Tags: characters, character-development, scene, perspective, altered-perspective

In the beginning of my story, my character wakes up in an unfamiliar apartment. Although they’re scared for their safety, they were sure nothing bad had happened to them that night. At first they were trying to find a way out, but then soon realized how this could benefit them. They are suffering from poverty and alcohol addiction, so they resort to stealing food, alcohol and clothing from the apartment before finding a way to escape. To add more context to the situation, they used to do petty crimes and pickpocket from others to survive and feed off their alcohol addiction. Is this still considered a "normal enough" reaction for a human to do?

"I drank so much that I didn’t even know myself when sober. When I wasn’t wasted on alcohol, I was wasted on misery and poverty.
Pulling the handles with my entire body, the doors finally opened and revealed a variety of enticing food, a variety that my eyes had never seen before. Without even missing a beat, I bent down towards a nearby cupboard that had a bunch of plastic bags and other miscellaneous items. Grabbing all of the bags, I knew what was going to happen next.
I was going to rob the place, stealing all of his precious food for myself."

Comment: Requests for critique are off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to making things in our stories believable doesn't lie in making them realistic, but in making them understandable.

This applies to character motivation just as much as it does sci-fi and fantasy world-building. If you share your character's worldview, and they see their actions as rational and justified, then the readers will work backward to imagine that character's personality.

For instance, if your character steals and robs to sustain their addiction but expresses remorse for their actions, that inherit contradiction might be more difficult to rationalize and understand than a character that rationalizes their actions as justified: it's their due, they've been wronged by the universe and this is payback, or it's no big deal, what they are taking won't be missed.

I imagine the latter description would be more believable than they first.